# How can I use the Windows look'n'feel for a system tray context menu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working with a `NotifyIcon` and `ContextMenuStrip`, I don't want to use the default menu look and feel which is shipped out of the box with this control which is different to Windows (Vista in my case) by using `contextMenu.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.ManagerRenderMode` or `contextMenu.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional`:

[image]

I don't want this using `contextMenu.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.System`:

[image]

I just want to use the standard, normal Windows "look and feel" as seen in countless, probably non-.net applications *grumble*:

[image]
[image]

Any ideas guys on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Vista, it renders correctly (i.e., the same way DropBox renders on my machine) when using all the defaults.

Here's a sample program that works for me. Try it, and if it doesn't render correctly for you, try uncommenting the two commented lines.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class AC : ApplicationContext
{
    NotifyIcon ni;
    public void menu_Quit(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ni.Dispose();
        ExitThread();
    }
    public AC()
    {
        ni = new NotifyIcon();
        ni.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.MenuItems.Add("Quit", new EventHandler(menu_Quit));
        ni.ContextMenu = menu;
        ni.Visible = true;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AC ac = new AC();
        Application.Run(ac);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks tyler, I found out what I was doing wrong with help from your example.  I was using a ContextMenuStrip when I should have been using a ContextMenu. Thanks.  Although not sure how they have made bold entry items now.  Shrug.  Probably overriden somehow.

Comment: Nah.  menuItem.DefaultItem it was.

Answer (score 0):

**For reference, this is how to get a notification icon with a Windows-styled context menu:**

1) In the controls toolbox, right-click All Windows Forms > Choose Items

2) Tick ContextMenu > OK

3) Right-click All Windows Forms > Sort Items Alphabetically

4) Drag the new ContextMenu into the form designer

5) Right-click ContextMenu1 > Properties > Rename it to something memorable (for future reference, I've renamed mine to `myNotifyIconContext`)

6) In the Solution Explorer, expand Form1.cs (etc) > Double-click Form1.Designer.cs

7) Find your notification icon - it will look something like this:

```
// 
// notifyIcon1
// 
this.notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
this.notifyIcon1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));
this.notifyIcon1.Text = "My Notification Icon";
this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
```

Here, I previously had a ContextMenuStrip.

8) Change the first line of code to (or add):

```
this.notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.myNotifyIconContext;
```

et voila!

[image]