# How to add an icon to a context menu

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a notification icon with a `ContextMenu` attached (rather than a `ContextMenuStrip`, in order to keep the Windows look-and-feel), [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718386/how-can-i-use-the-windows-looknfeel-for-a-system-tray-context-menu/13598945#13598945).

How can I add an icon to the context menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ***have*** to use a MenuItem, you'll have to draw the menuitem yourself and add an image. For that, set the `OwnerDraw` property to true and subscribe to the `DrawItem` event.

**Or**

You can derive your own MenuItem class:

```
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public MyMenuItem()
    {
        OwnerDraw = true;

    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);

        // Add paint logic here
    }
}
```

For specific links on how to draw on the MenuItem see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4332/Putting-Images-Next-To-MenuItems-In-A-Menu-in-C) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/OwnerDrawnMenuControl.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you able to give me any pointers (or URLs) or where to begin trying to draw/paint the menu item myself? I've never overridden controls before. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! Just one more question, you said if I "**have** to use a MenuItem"... what alternative is there?

Comment: Had you used the `ContextMenuStrip`, you could have used the `ToolStripMenuItem` class which has an `Image` property.

Comment: Ah, yes! But sadly not, `ContextMenuStrip` has a fugly style.